# Filtering table based on row non-zero values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, filtering, subset

I have a table like the following:

```
date X1 X2 X3
1/1   0  3 34 
2/1   0  7 65
3/1   0 13  0
4/1  25  4 65
5/1  35  0  0
6/1   4  6  9
7/1   0  0  0
```

How can I use `dplyr` to select rows only after all Xs start appearing non-zero values. In that case, select only rows for dates `4/1`, `5/1`, `6/1` and `7/1`. Thank you.

Comment: I'm wondering.. are you interested in rows starting from a row which contains no zero, or rows starting from a row where al. Xs have been non-zero at least once? I.e., if the 4 for X2 changed in 4/1 changed to 0, would you still want to select the same rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df %>%
   filter(cumsum(if_all(starts_with('X'), ~.x > 0))>0)

  date X1 X2 X3
1  4/1 25  4 65
2  5/1 35  0  0
3  6/1  4  6  9
4  7/1  0  0  0
```

or even:

```
df %>%
   filter(cumsum(if_all(starts_with('X'))>0)>0)

  date X1 X2 X3
1  4/1 25  4 65
2  5/1 35  0  0
3  6/1  4  6  9
4  7/1  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cumsum` + `rowSums`

```
> subset(df, cumsum(rowSums(df[-1] > 0) == length(df) - 1) > 0)
  date X1 X2 X3
4  4/1 25  4 65
5  5/1 35  0  0
6  6/1  4  6  9
7  7/1  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly:

```r
df[apply(apply(df[, -1], 
               2, \(col) cumsum(col > 0)), 
         1, prod) > 0, ]

#   date X1 X2 X3
# 4  4/1 25  4 65
# 5  5/1 35  0  0
# 6  6/1  4  6  9
# 7  7/1  0  0  0
```